# Setting static ip via powershell doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, networking, powershell

I am trying to configure automatically a static ip address for a local network of pc.

The computers are using Windows 10 and I would like to use a PowerShell script to automate the process of configuration.

I tried the following sequence of instructions

```
# We remove possible remaining configurations
Remove-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias Ethernet
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias Ethernet -AddressFamily IPv4 -Dhcp Disable
New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias Ethernet -AddressFamily IPv4 -IPAddress 10.168.1.3  -PrefixLength 24 \
   -DefaultGateway 10.168.1.1
```

When doing so I get the following error message:

```
new-NetIPAddress : Inconsistent parameters PolicyStore PersistentStore and Dhcp Enabled
At line:1 char:1
```

The stranger things is that if I use the graphical interface going to the **change adapter settings** the TCP/IPv4 settings has disabled the DHCP, that is the static IP settings are set, though the IP, Netmask, and Gateway are unset.

Have you got any idea on what is really going on here and how can the problem be solved?

Answer (score 0):

The article
[Using PowerShell to Set Static and DHCP IP Addresses – Part 1](https://www.pdq.com/blog/using-powershell-to-set-static-and-dhcp-ip-addresses-part-1/)
has this PowerShell script that you could adapt to your needs:

```
$IP = "10.10.10.10"
$MaskBits = 24 # This means subnet mask = 255.255.255.0
$Gateway = "10.10.10.1"
$Dns = "10.10.10.100"
$IPType = "IPv4"
# Retrieve the network adapter that you want to configure
$adapter = Get-NetAdapter | ? {$_.Status -eq "up"}
# Remove any existing IP, gateway from our ipv4 adapter
If (($adapter | Get-NetIPConfiguration).IPv4Address.IPAddress) {
 $adapter | Remove-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily $IPType -Confirm:$false
}
If (($adapter | Get-NetIPConfiguration).Ipv4DefaultGateway) {
 $adapter | Remove-NetRoute -AddressFamily $IPType -Confirm:$false
}
 # Configure the IP address and default gateway
$adapter | New-NetIPAddress `
 -AddressFamily $IPType `
 -IPAddress $IP `
 -PrefixLength $MaskBits `
 -DefaultGateway $Gateway
# Configure the DNS client server IP addresses
$adapter | Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ServerAddresses $DNS
```